# Change version release control in iTunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I submitted an app update in iTunes Connect and set the version release control to Hold for Developer Release. I want to change it to release automatically (it is still waiting for review). Is this possible, and if so, how do I make this change?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've torn through iTunes connect extensively and there doesn't seem to be a way to change an automatic release to Hold for Developer, or a Hold for Developer marked release to automatic release.  It seems to be set upon creation of the version and uneditable.

There may be a way to do this by rejecting the binary and starting the process over, but I haven't had a chance to test this as I don't have any pending releases and nothing currently ready to be updated.

Comment: Rejecting the binary and reuploading will allow you you to change the Release Control, but note that doing so will push the app to the end of the review queue.

Answer (score 1):

Funny, I came across this post yesterday because I needed to change this setting. Today, Apple updated iTunes Connect and it's now possible to change this option right on the binary page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't, but if you want to you can go to **rights and pricing** and move the availability date to a later date. Users won't be able to download you app during that time, but the  update won't be available to existing users either when new version gets approved.